# Sorting list of elements of the form [x=value1, x=value2,...] in maxima

Tags: sorting, lisp, maxima, numerical-integration

When I use either solve or allroots method I obtain a list of elements that is not sorted. The problem is that I want to sort that list but I can't because it is of the form [x=value1,x=value2,x=value3] and sort function doesn't work well with these x= expressions. Do you how to solve this?

**Background**

My problem arises in the context of gaussian quadrature while obtaining the roots of Legendre Polynomials. In order to obtain the coefficients of the formula I need to integrate Lagrange polynomials and to do so I need to have the list ordered.

Comment: Please give an example of a list which is not sorted as you wish.

Comment: For the Legendre polynomial of order 3, using allroots I obtain [x=0.0,x=0.77459666924148,x=-0.77459666924148] and I have to manually order the list which avoids me to implement a function that does the whole process

Comment: Well, I get `(%i1) sort([x=0.0,x=0.77459666924148,x=-0.77459666924148]);` yields `[x = - 0.77459666924148, x = 0.0, x = 0.77459666924148]`. Isn't that what you want? Do you get something different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gather that what you want is to sort by the right-hand side values and obtain just the right-hand side.

```
(%i1) allroots (x^3 - 3*x);
(%o1)      [x = 0.0, x = 1.732050807568877, x = - 1.732050807568877]
(%i2) sort (map (rhs, %o1));
(%o2)            [- 1.732050807568877, 0.0, 1.732050807568877]
```

or equivalently in this case

```
(%i3) map (rhs, sort (%o1));
(%o3)            [- 1.732050807568877, 0.0, 1.732050807568877]
```

since `sort` will sort general expressions.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem using ev function although some people said they used rhs function as follows:

```
r:allroots(p);
r:sort(makelist(ev(x,r[i]),i,n+1),"<");
```

where the last statement removes the x=... expressions and orders the points.

Comment: This is somewhat more complicated than it needs to be.